# Get list of dlls in a directory with MSBuild

Tags: msbuild

The following gives me only 1 file, the exe:

```
<ItemGroup>
      <AssembliesToMerge Include="$(MSBuildProjectDirectory)\App\bin\Release\*.*" Condition="'%(Extension)'=='.dll'"/>
      <AssembliesTomerge Include="$(MSbuildProjectDirectory)\App\bin\Release\App.exe"/>
</ItemGroup>
```

If I remove the Condition attribute, AssembliesToMerge contains all the files in the directory--dlls and otherwise.  What am I doing wrong?

I am testing this via the ILMerge MSBuildCommunityExtensions Task.  If there is a way to directly print the items in the ItemGroup, then that might help to ensure it's an issue with the Condition attribute.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use a wildcard in **Include** to filter dll files ([Items wildcard](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171453.aspx#b8d2962e-4a93-406a-8e5d-f9f326351e14))

```
<ItemGroup>
  <AssembliesToMerge Include="$(MSBuildProjectDirectory)\App\bin\Release\*.dll"/>
  <AssembliesTomerge Include="$(MSbuildProjectDirectory)\App\bin\Release\App.exe"/>
</ItemGroup>
```

I think it doesn't work using the **Condition** attribute because Item metadatas aren't set yet during creation, so `%(Extension)` is empty.